# How to execute a command on multiple hosts using IPv6 only?

Tags: unix, shell, ipv6, command-line-interface

First of all there is [pdsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdsh/) which is essentially a parallel distributed shell which may execute commands on a list of given hosts. However, I find myself in an IPv6 only problem setting. It seems that pdsh is not able to use IPv6, as I am getting error messages:

```
pdsh -w ^hostnames my_command
pdsh@myhost: gethostbyname("foobar") failed
```

I also tried to use IPv6 addresses only, which also didn't work. So how do you run a single shell script for administrative purpose (no SGE stuff, or similar) on a bunch of hosts that is IPv6 reachable only?

Comment: It seems to be a somewhat active project. So you file a bug report.

Comment: gethostbyname is the old IPv4-only way to resolve a hostname. The code needs fixing :-)

Comment: From pdsh-users mailing list: "If you use ssh protocol instead, ssh should be resolving hostnames instead of pdsh, so that could be a workaoround at this time."

Answer (score 1):

[ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) can SSH into multiple hosts and replicate your keystrokes to all or a subset of the hosts you have connected to. It works on Linux and a couple of UNIXes. ClusterSSH can be used interactively or you can supply a command to run on the remote host using the -a flag. However, as far as I know, it requires an X server because it is a GUI application.

On my system, it uses OpenSSH to open the SSH connection so it is able to reach IPv6-only destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ssh daemons running, and they've been bound to the IP6 interface (/etc/ssh/sshd_config ListenAddress) The following shell script should more or less do what you want:

```
for  hostName in `cat serverList.txt`
do
    (ssh userName@$hostName  'command' &) 2>&1 >> "${hostname}.log"
done
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677542/ssh-and-bring-up-many-processes-in-parallel-solaris

Answer (score 0):

I like Dancer's Shell / Distributed Shell:

http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html

Since it uses SSH, if your hosts are reachable over IPv6 and run sshd then you'll be fine.

It's packaged in Debian and Ubuntu at least.